# How do devices connect to a remembered wifi network in a different location?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, wifi-configuration

For example, when I connect to "Starbucks Wifi" once on my phone, it will automatically connect to any "Starbucks Wifi" in all establishments. How does it know that a "Starbucks Wifi" is legitimately part of Starbucks? Anybody can rename their wifi to be "Starbucks Wifi".

What non-spoofable value is being shared across all those starbucks networks?

Comment: Really, the only ID for the initial connection is the network name, whether broadcast or hidden. The PC is not looking for MAC ID or any other ID, so the name **is easily spoofed**, i.e., subject to impersonation. For that reason, and others, one should limit use of PII, passwords, etc., in a public location.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Oh i see. I guess a MITM attack is really easy, as a victim doesn't even need to explicitly connect to something.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it know that a "Starbucks Wifi" is legitimately part of Starbucks?

It doesn't. You also don't.

(Indeed, when you went there for the first time, the phone *also* didn't know whether you were connecting to a legitimate "Starbucks Wifi" before it was remembered.)

> What non-spoofable value is being shared across all those starbucks networks?

Literally none.

(If the real network requires a passphrase, then the fake network also has to use the *same* passphrase; it can't just say "sure, that's correct" to anything – but of course that's not non-spoofable, just slightly more effort to spoof.)

---

The only way to make a network difficult to spoof is to use the *WPA-Enterprise* security mode (the kind that requires username and your individual password) – you see those at large corporations or universities; one world-wide example is the `eduroam` network available across most universities.

With WPA-Enterprise, the client device actually establishes a TLS connection as part of the Wi-Fi connect handshake (e.g. using EAP-TTLS or EAP-PEAP) and it can verify the authentication server's TLS certificate against a domain you've entered, just like web browsers do. Although anyone else can set up a fake network with the same SSID, they will not be able to obtain the correct TLS certificate.

(Though not all devices care – e.g. before Android 7, "no verification" was the default choice...)

Comment: Why can't the fake network say sure to anything? Also, the network in my scenario has no password, like how starbucks wifi usually is

Comment: Because it doesn't actually get to _see_ the passphrase from the client -- there is no  "here's my password" "ok that works" exchange. The network has to already know the passphrase in order to generate the correct encryption key for WPA. (Hence why it's called a "PSK" or "pre-shared key" a lot of the time.)

Answer (score 0):

The "fake network" inded might not have a password and no security. It might well be hidden and if your devicr is configured  to autoconnect to "known wifi networks", it can easily connect and even push your network out. You can end up networking with the fake network for a very lomg time before you are aware of the successful hyjack. In an ectrene example,  it is possible to comfigure and deploy a netgear guest network as a hidden network with the exact sane ssid as a workimg primary network while the latter is in operation. It takes only secomds using a specific Netgear comfiguration app at 192.168.1.1. Here, the hidden  guest network can also be congigured to interact  directly with the primary network whlie it is running its device and change systej settings. It can usurp the running network, change settings so that its creator becomes a firm "man im the middle" and take control of even the most sophisticated  abd otherwise secute devices without knowing the wifi password and without being detected by even well experienced  users. Why Netgear developed this app (tge configutation app) and allowed this app to provide hidden networks is beyond me, but now that ive exposed this little bug, the company  should  immediately withdrawl  this  app, provide a fix.Quite frankly, its obscene!

Since the network deployed to hyjack the device is "hidden", or not broadcasting its sscd,  there teally is no need for sevurity: as a result, the victim diesnt  need to ebter a password as aurocomnect quickly meets and welvomes  the spoofing guest network. Later the hacker can delete his guest network and teplace it with a primary network with identical chatacteristics as the network he just hacked. Here the hacker can easily  glean the network  password when the victim tries hopelessly to reconnect to his displaced netwotk. Again, no password was needed to gain access, displace the user"s legit network and take comtrol of the networkrd device; none at all. Now the havker can get the legit password too, and use it later still unbeknown to the legit user.

In the evebt that the hackers wifi isnt right next door, most router are amendable to a power booster so that the hyjackers network appears These can maje your neighvors to be just as strong as the legit network was.

You just cant tell the differene.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).